# Find the list of post by tag ids in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, tags

I need to add filter for find post by multiple tag ids. like i have 10 tags. In front end i have list of 100 posts. Now when user click on tag 1 then i need to find only those posts that contain tag 1. User can select multiple tags like tag 1 and tag 4 then i need to find those posts that contain tag 1 and tag 4.

**Note : Need to search by tag Id.**

My code :

```
$args = array(
                'showposts' => -1, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
                'post_type' => 'gampudi',
                'orderby' => 'ID',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'tag_id' => implode(',',$_POST['selectedTags']) // [1,4]
            );
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

This code is not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tag__in` and pass the `$_POST['selectedTags']`.

```
$args = array(
    'showposts' => -1, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
    'post_type' => 'gampudi',
    'orderby'   => 'ID',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'tag__in'   => $_POST['selectedTags']
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: @Pritesh Mahajan does my answer help?